# How to use jQuery to substitute text with a function of itself

Tags: jquery

I have the following

```
<div class="change">a</div>
<div class="keep">b</div>
<div class="change">c</div>
<div class="change">d</div>
<div class="keep">e</div>
<div class="change">f</div>
```

I need one jQuery statment to make all elements with `class="change"` to be uppercase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    $(".change").each(function(){
        
        var str = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
        
        $(this).text(str);
        
    })
    
})
```

```html
<div class="change">a</div>
<div class="keep">b</div>
<div class="change">c</div>
<div class="change">d</div>
<div class="keep">e</div>
<div class="change">f</div>
        
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: each! I was missing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need jquery for this, You can easily do it with css.

```css
.change {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  }
```

```html
<div class="change">a</div>
<div class="keep">b</div>
<div class="change">c</div>
<div class="change">d</div>
<div class="keep">e</div>
<div class="change">f</div>
```

Comment: My case is just an example, an oversimplification of what I need to do.